# Random variables on an $n$-point sample space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I am reading the book *An Introduction to Quantum Stochastic Calculus* recently. And the author says **random variables on an *n*-point sample space constitute a real linear space of dimension *n*** without any proof. In my opinion this means that there exists random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ such that for any random variable $X$, it can be written as a real linear combination of $X_i$. Is my way of understanding right? How can I prove it if it is right. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A random variable on an $n$ point sample space $S=\{s_1,\dots,s_n\}$ (endowed with the $\sigma$-algebra of all subsets and some probability measure $P$), is simply a function from $S$ to $\mathbb R$, and the space of these functions, $\mathbb R^S$,
is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. Each vector $v \in \mathbb R^n$ corresponds to the function $f_v : S \to \mathbb R$ with $f_v(s_i)=v_i$ for every $i \le n$.

Comment: Could you show me in detail why the space of these functions is $\mathbb R^S$ @Yuval Peres  Thank you so much !!

Comment: Ok, I added details. It should be clear.